# button javascript works on IE but not firefox window.navigate()

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="window.navigate('http://www.google.com')">
```

This works on IE8, but not firefox or opera. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check [the documentation for that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536638(VS.85).aspx), you will see the quite common:

*There is no public standard that applies to this method.*

This means that it's a non-standard feature that most likely only works in Internet Explorer.

This will work:

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com';">
```

If you are using XHTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com';" />
```

Answer (score 5):

.navigate() only works in IE.

Try setting the window.location.

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
```

Comment: You should really have the .href on it.

Comment: I've never had a problem leaving it off, but you're probably right. Updated.

Comment: Leaving the .href out is the most compatible (cross-browser) way to navigate to another URL. window.location.href doesn't work in FF 1.5, but window.location does.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

- [links want to be links](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/links.html)
- links [afford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance) navigation, buttons afford actions. This is navigation
- [depending on JS](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) is a bad idea

… and "back" is a poor choice of link text. Either a link or your IE specific JS will take the user **forward**. It will add a URL to the end of the user's history. It won't activate the browser's Forward functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='button' value='click' onclick="window.location='http://google.com';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For searchers on this problem: Ensure your input not post to current page like sumbit. In this case any navigate methods will not work. 
To fix this add `event.preventDefault()` on click handler

Answer (score 0):

> `window.navigate` is a non-standard Internet Explorer feature. Other
>   browsers simply don't provide the function.
>
> You could shim it with:
>
> ```
> if (! window.navigate) {
>     window.navigate = function (arg) {
>     location.assign(arg);
>    } 
> }
> ```
>
> … but your code would be better if you just rewrote it to use
>   standard methods (i.e. the location object) in the first place.

**Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793432/6737444**