# window.navigate error

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [button javasript works on IE but not firefox window.navigate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112093/button-javasript-works-on-ie-but-not-firefox-window-navigate)

I would like my page to navigate after selecting a select item.

I got the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'navigate'**

```
    function go(to)
{
    window.navigate("feltoltott_kepek_elozmeny.php?show="+to);
}


onchange="javascript:go(this.value)"
```

Could somebody help me?
Thanks.

I got more than one solution. Which one should I choose? Which is working in every browser?

Comment: also see [Should I use window.navigate or document.location in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948227/should-i-use-window-navigate-or-document-location-in-javascript)

Comment: also  javascript: in an event handler is only necessary in IE when you have a VBScript as the first script block in the page. Nowhere else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please use

```
window.location.href = "feltoltott_kepek_elozmeny.php?show=" + to;
```

Comment: window.navigate() is the IE-specific way of assigning a value to the window.location.href property :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
window.location.href = YOUR_URL;
```

;)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `window.location.assign()`:

```
function go(to) {
    window.location.assign("feltoltott_kepek_elozmeny.php?show=" + to);
}
```

You can also assign a value directly to `window.location` or `window.location.href`:

```
window.location = "feltoltott_kepek_elozmeny.php?show=" + to;
window.location.href = "feltoltott_kepek_elozmeny.php?show=" + to;
```

See the [Mozilla docs for `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Comment: Never seen .assign - and it seems to be the default method anyway: [Whenever a property of the location object is modified, a document will be loaded using the URL as if window.location.assign() had been called with the modified URL.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Methods)

Comment: @mplungjan: I can vaguely remember it, but I've always been using the `location.href` approach. Perhaps the method exists in case someone is feels more comfortable with using functions.

Comment: @Leken I really should load MDC and read every page. Seems every time I go there, I see something I did not know or that changed over the years. Still my (old-skool) coding works on all browsers still :)