# Window.Navigate Method Not Working in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [button javasript works on IE but not firefox window.navigate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112093/button-javasript-works-on-ie-but-not-firefox-window-navigate)

**I want pass Question ID to Answer Page Along with URL but it's not working on Chrome and Firefox I'm using ASP.Net,**

---

> Navigate Method is not working , what are other methods for this ?

---

```
function display(QuestionID)

{

 window.navigate("Answer.aspx?TutID=" + QuestionID);

}
```

please Help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112093/button-javasript-works-on-ie-but-not-firefox-window-navigate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url = "Answer.aspx?TutID=" + QuestionID;

location.href = url;
```